# Why does my code work on Playgrounds but not CoderPad?

Tags: swift

I have a very simple func in Xcode playgrounds which works when I run it. But when i try to run the same code in CoderPad it gives me the following error `Solution.swift:18:1: warning: result of call to 'isPalindrome(word:)' is unused
isPalindrome(word:"racecar")`

Here is the code

```
import Foundation


func isPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool{

  var oddCharacters: Set<Character> = []

  for char in word {
    if oddCharacters.contains(char){
      oddCharacters.remove(char)
    }else{
      oddCharacters.insert(char)
    }
  }
  return oddCharacters.count <= 1
}

isPalindrome(word:"racecar")
```

I really do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: I hope you were able to debug this code and correct it. It returns true for "rrracecar" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means, that the "left-hand-side" result of the call to your function `isPalindrome(word: "racecar")` is unused ("wasted").

It seems that for a debugging, testing, try-out environment like a Playground it's just okay to find out the result of this call (`true`) without *storing* it inside a variable. However, when doing that in other development environments, the compiler will be complaining about that. I can give you four options that would prevent the error from being thrown, just to give you a better idea of *why* the compiler is complaining:

1. If you want to use it in your further code below, just store the result and change your calling line to `let isPalindrome = isPalindrome(word: "racecar")`. But if you don't use it, the compiler will give you a warning again saying that you're never using your `isPalindrome` variable... --> Option 2
2. If you don't need the result, you can also just say: `_ = isPalindrome(word: "racecar")`. That will explicitly tell the compiler "bro, it's okay if the result is just ignored". It wouldn't make much sense for this function, though.
3. You can add the `@discardableResult` keyword prior to your function declaration, so it would say: `@discardableResult func isPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool { ...` That would kinda just silence your thrown error and like option 2 just tell the compiler that it's okay to just ignore the result of this function.
4. Just use the result in any way like:

```swift
if isPalindrome(word: "racecar") {
   // do something 
} else {
   // do something else
}

// or

print("racecar is a palindrome: \(isPalindrome(word: "racecar")")
```

and everything will just be fine. I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import Foundation



func isPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool{

  var oddCharacters: Set<Character> = []

  for char in word {
    if oddCharacters.contains(char){
      oddCharacters.remove(char)
    }else{
      oddCharacters.insert(char)
    }
  }
  return oddCharacters.count <= 1
}




print(isPalindrome(word:"racecar"))
```

all you had to do was print it, hope this helped

Comment: please also take a look at my answer to learn **why** that error is thrown, for your better understanding

Comment: I knew why it would throw, how else would I be able to find the answer ;)

Comment: Ah ok, ok my bad!